# is there a way to find my phonegap app url?

Tags: jquery, cordova

Id like to add the dropbox chooser for file uploads to my phonegap app.

At the moment, it doesn't work because the chooser plugin doesn't allow cross-domain calls ( you have to specify what domain the call will be coming from, works fine on a real site, not good on an app ).

Apparently each app has a url.. but how do I find it? does an app only get one once its gone through the itunes store or can I get it for testing purposes?

I don't mind using jquery to find it in-app or if there's another way to get it

Comment: You can output `window.location.href` to see the url, but are you sure about this?  It's like saying a browser on your PC has a url.  (I've only done very little with Phonegap.)

Comment: yeh, im looking for the app url which will look something like: app://60e28ac7-dcb3-6d4c-9ade-65feffcf57e6

Comment: In that case, just display `window.location.href` and that should be the app url.